# Create Domain in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Please help me to create domain in MySQL.
I have tried to run the followoing statement in MySQL but got syntax error:

```
create domain age as int(2);
```

Comment: Please share more details - if you receive any syntax error, what makes you think that the query is correct?

Answer (score 18):

MySQL doesn't support user-defined domains, so it is not possible to run a `CREATE DOMAIN` statement.

Comment: and what about MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL does support user-defined types. They can be created with CREATE TYPE.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is not ok. I don't think that CREATE DOMAIN is supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Both MySQL and MariaDB currently lack this feature. `DOMAIN`s are a method of associating a constraint with a type creating a pseudo-user defined type. Those constraints that will otherwise be attached to the DOMAIN will have to be placed on everything that uses that type, and managed there.

I opened a [feature request SQL Standard DOMAIN functionality, MDEV-16377](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16377)

For more information, see

- [Creating a DOMAIN in MySQL or MariaDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/121471/2639)

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options if you really miss domains:

1. use [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/domain/)
2. use [Sets or Enums](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/enum/)
3. in MySqlWorkbench create User Defined Types

   They are just alias to already existing types, but if you're using MySqlWorkbench you can define new types and reuse in you're models.

   [image]
   [image]

Comment: @pfreire: Careful with that link, it's not the MariaDB manual, it's a link to the book "SQL-99 Complete, Really" hosted on mariadb.com. MariaDB doesn't support domains (yet).