# Is it possible to define domain constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dns

Is it possible to define domain constraints in MySQL?

By domain constraints I mean simply defining domains with data types, for instance:

```
CREATE DOMAIN Name
AS varchar(20)
```

Sadly I did not find an answer to this questions on the Web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Domain in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693991/create-domain-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way, you can define this by using ENUM. Here's an example to this: -

CREATE TABLE test_table(
 testTable_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 test_gender ENUM('male', 'female', 'other')
)

Answer (score 0):

No. MySQL does not support domains or user defined data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, in MySQL:

CREATE TABLE `teste2` (
`numero` int NOT NULL,
`numero2` int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `teste2_chk_1` CHECK ((`numero` > 10)),
CONSTRAINT `teste2_chk_2` CHECK ((`numero2` >= `numero`))
);