# SQL_Create domain

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit confused about the create domain and about what it does actually. Suppose I have the following:
Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)

```
create domain HotelNo as char(4);

create table Hotel (
hotelNo HotelNo NOT NULL,
primary key (hotelNo)
);

create domain RoomNo as int;

create table Room (
roomNo RoomNo not null , 
hotelNo HotelNo NOT NULL, --already used domain HotelNo
primary key (roomNo,hotelNo),
foreign key(hotelNo) references Hotel on delete no action on update cascade
);
```

In the solution for this question, the lecturer has put this code:

```
CREATE DOMAIN HotelNumbers AS HotelNo
 CHECK(VALUE IN (SELECT hotelNo FROM Hotel));
```

My question is, does it makes a difference whether we use the domain HotelNo or domain HotelNumbers(like the lecturer did)?

Comment: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693991/create-domain-in-mysql) about `CREATE DOMAIN` in MySQL.