# Need to create domain to constrain values in table to specific values, keep getting errors

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I'm trying to create a table that has values for a specific values in a specific column.

```
CREATE TABLE employee2 (
    ID numeric(5, 0),
    F_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MI char(1),
    L_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Add_street varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    Add_city varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Add_state char(2) NOT NULL,
    Add_zip numeric (5, 0),
    Title varchar(20),
    Type varchar(18)
    );
```

I need the Type column to only allow 3 things "python", "javascript", "html".

I've tried creating a domain:

```
CREATE DOMAIN ee_type varchar(18) CONSTRAINT type_constraint CHECK (Type='python', 'javascript', 'html'));
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
mysql> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DOMAIN ee_type varchar(18) CHECK (Type='python'))' at line 1
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware that MySQL supports `CREATE DOMAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL currently does not support domains. You can find more info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1693991/245915).

Instead, you can you use [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html), like this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee2 (
    ID numeric(5, 0),
    F_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MI char(1),
    L_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Add_street varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    Add_city varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Add_state char(2) NOT NULL,
    Add_zip numeric (5, 0),
    Title varchar(20),
    Type ENUM('python', 'javascript', 'html')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After realizing I'm using the wrong language, I was able to resolve with the following format for Postgresql:

```
CREATE DOMAIN ee_type varchar(18) CHECK (VALUE IN('software developer', 'administration', 'support staff'));

CREATE TABLE employee3 (
    ID numeric(5, 0),
    F_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MI char(1),
    L_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Add_street varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    Add_city varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Add_state char(2) NOT NULL,
    Add_zip numeric(5, 0),
    Title varchar(20),
    Type ee_type
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want python, javascript and html to be the only values added in the type column then you can use the below query.

create table emp2(emp_id int, emp_name char(25), emp_salary double, type varchar(255) check(type in ("python","javascript","html")));

I have not used the exact columns as yours but I have used the type column. So here the **in** operator will help us to accept only the value that is either python, javascript or html. So if the value you are putting for the type column is python or javascript or html then it will be a successful query. No other value will be accepted. If you try to add a different value other than the values mentioned in the check constraint then an error saying Check constraint 'tablename_chk_1' is violated will be shown to you.